# JOLT Transformation Rename & Remove based on null value

Tags: json, transformation, jolt

I want to transform this JSON:

```json
[
  {
    "payload": {
      "before": {
        "order_id": 3110445250,
        "data": "2022-06-10",
        "ora": "08:08:00",
        "test1": "2022-06-10T00:00:00.000Z",
        "test2": "2022-06-10T03:00:00.000Z"
      },
      "after": null,
      "source": {
        "file": "delta.000002",
        "pos": 8362,
        "row": 0,
        "thread": null,
        "query": null
      },
      "op": "c",
      "ts_ms": 1654851760103,
      "transaction": null
    }
  }
]
```

Desired output:

if "after" is null then remove "after" and rename "before" to "final"

else if "before" is null then remove "before" and rename after to "final"

else if "after" is not null and "before" is not null then remove "before" and rename after to "final"

```json
[
  {
    "payload": {
      "before": {
        "order_id": 3110445250,
        "data": "2022-06-10",
        "ora": "08:08:00",
        "test1": "2022-06-10T00:00:00.000Z",
        "test2": "2022-06-10T03:00:00.000Z"
      },
      "source": {
        "file": "delta.000002",
        "pos": 8362,
        "row": 0,
        "thread": null,
        "query": null
      },
      "op": "c",
      "ts_ms": 1654851760103,
      "transaction": null
    }
  }
]
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a conditional logic within a **shift** transformation after determining the **size**s of before/after objects/attributes through use of a **modify** transformation in which we compute their respective sizes whether they return a value. In cases the value doesn't return, then **-1** is assigned to determine the element(object or attribute) to be ***null*** such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "payload": {
          "before_sz": ["=size(@(1,before))", -1],
          "after_sz": ["=size(@(1,after))", -1]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "payload": {
          "before_sz": {
            "-1": {
              "@(2,after_sz)": {
                "-1": { "": "" },
                "*": { "@(4,after)": "[&6].&5.final" }
              }
            },
            "*": {
              "@(2,after_sz)": {
                "-1": { "@(4,before)": "[&6].&5.final" },
                "*": { "@(4,after)": "[&6].&5.final" }
              }
            }
          },
          "*": "[&2].&1.&"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "remove",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "payload": {
          "after_sz": "",
          "after": "",
          "before_sz": "",
          "before": ""
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "sort"
  }
]
```

that will return

```json
[
  {
    "payload": {
      "final": {
        "data": "2022-06-10",
        "ora": "08:08:00",
        "order_id": 3110445250,
        "test1": "2022-06-10T00:00:00.000Z",
        "test2": "2022-06-10T03:00:00.000Z"
      },
      "op": "c",
      "source": {
        "file": "delta.000002",
        "pos": 8362,
        "query": null,
        "row": 0,
        "thread": null
      },
      "transaction": null,
      "ts_ms": 1654851760103
    }
  }
]
```

for the current input as a sample case.

***PS.***: as a missing case for the *question* : if both `after`/`before` are ***null***, then both are removed within this solution.

**Edit** : If the input is not nested within square brackets(*as you asked as an extra case*), then convert the spec to this one :

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "payload": {
        "before_sz": ["=size(@(1,before))", -1],
        "after_sz": ["=size(@(1,after))", -1]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "payload": {
        "before_sz": {
          "-1": {
            "@(2,after_sz)": {
              "-1": { "": "" },
              "*": { "@(4,after)": "&5.final" }
            }
          },
          "*": {
            "@(2,after_sz)": {
              "-1": { "@(4,before)": "&5.final" },
              "*": { "@(4,after)": "&5.final" }
            }
          }
        },
        "*": "&1.&"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "remove",
    "spec": {
      "payload": {
        "after_sz": "",
        "after": "",
        "before_sz": "",
        "before": ""
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "sort"
  }
]
```

Comment: May I kindly ask you one more question? How should I change the JOLT spec if the input JSON is not an array?
  {"payload": {
      "before": {
        "order_id": 3110445250,
        "data": "2022-06-10",
        "ora": "08:08:00",
        "test1": "2022-06-10T00:00:00.000Z",
        "test2": "2022-06-10T03:00:00.000Z"
      },
      "after": null,
      "source": {
        "file": "delta.000002",
        "pos": 8362,
        "row": 0,
        "thread": null,
        "query": null
      },
      "op": "c",
      "ts_ms": 1654851760103,
      "transaction": null
    }
  }

Comment: Hi @CristiCiucu , you're welcome. I've edited as you desired. Have a nice day!

Comment: @CristiCiucu Were you able to retry along with the new edit ?

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot, is working as I expected 